# How to enable Configuration Editor in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

I'm working on a Server 2008 32 bit machine with IIS 7.0.  I would like to install/enable the "Configuration Editor" because I don't see it by default when I select the server in the connections tree view.  I thought it was supposed to come installed on IIS 7, but this article seems to indicate a need for an additional download.
"The IIS 7.0 Administration Pack adds to the set of management features that ship with IIS 7.0 "...https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/administration-pack

I tried to download the "Administration Pack" per the article above, but all links to this are broken.

I've looked through the features and file services in the server manager, but I don't see an option to install.  Is this part of another package that I need to enable?  Are there other functional download links for the administration pack?

Answer (score 0):

Which OS/Server are you using ?

Configuration Editor is included in [Adminisration Pack](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/administration-pack) for IIS 7.0.

The functionality of the Administration Pack was integrated into the Windows Server 2008 R2/Windows 7 installation. You don't need to install additional Extension since IIS 7.5

Comment: Windows Server 2008 (service pack 2) 32 bit machine with IIS 7.0.The download link listed for admin pack above is broken.